# Finite differenced eigenvalue prob. of inhomogeneous boundary conditions?

Tags: finite-element, finite-difference, ode, boundary-conditions, eigenvalues

I am basically asking about *eigenvalue problems* of differential equations using some finite difference method (FDM). Usually the system is subject to some boundary conditions (BC), e.g., Dirichlet or Neumann. Often it is homogeneous BC like $u(0)=0,u'(R)=0$, which seems to be fine to deal with. One way is to introduce and then eliminate ghost points with the BC.

But if it is ***inhomogeneous BC*** (e.g., for a Dirichlet $u(0)=a,u(R)=b$), the nonzero constants have a sting in the tail. Effectively they're put into an inhomogeneous column as shown below, which is also clearly introduced in [this note](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mpugh/Teaching/Mat1062/notes2.pdf). For instance, the eigenvalue probelm $Lu=\lambda u$ of the operator $L=-\frac{\partial^2}{{\partial x}^2}$ becomes an *inhomogeneous eigenvalue problem* $Mu+R=\lambda u$ with
$$M=\frac{1}{h^2}\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-1 & & & \\
-1 &2 &-1 & & \\
&\ddots  &\ddots &\ddots & \\
& & -1 &2 &-1\\
 & & & -1 &2
\end{bmatrix},
R=\frac{1}{h^2}\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0\\
 b
\end{bmatrix}.$$

***But after this, practically how to proceed to solve the original problem?*** Any other formulation? Or we simply don't need to think about such problem for some reason?

This may not be a problem for usual DE solving (I naively assume one-sided stencil often suffices.). But for eigenvalue case, I can't find any way out. The *inhomogeneous eigenvalue problem* doesn't have any standard or general solution as far as I've searched.

Comment: back up for a sec here: does it really make sense to set inhomogeneous BCs to such an eigenvalue problem? after all, you're looking for nontrivial solutions (eigenvalue/eigenfunction pairs) to the corresponding _homogeneous_ problem (with homogeneous BCs of either Dirichlet or Neumann type). have a look at how `chebfun`'s `eigs` function computes eigenvalues of differential operators - either [here](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/713/NA-08-11.pdf), or in chapter 6 of Nick Trefethen's ["Exploring ODEs" book](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/Exploring.pdf)